# How can I convert RestApi object data to Array?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, rest, object

How can I convert this data from PokeApi to Array? I can't call it in html in Angular because I can't assign it to the Array. It gives an error because its return is Object ..

```
 getPokemonDetail(index) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/pokemon/${index}`).pipe(
      map((poke) => {
        let sprites = Object.keys(poke['sprites']);
        poke['images'] = sprites
          .map((spriteKey) => poke['sprites'][spriteKey])
          .filter((img) => img);
        return poke;
      })
    );
  }
```

**I uploaded the code on github can someone check where the error is?
unfortunately I didn't manage :(**

[github link](https://github.com/meminsahin/pokedex-app)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1**

Since Angular 6, there is now a keyvalue pipe operator. Simple do the following for working in html

```
*ngFor="for item in objectList | keyvalue"
```

**Solution2**

For converting object to array, just put that object inside [].suppose if your object is in image variable, then

```
Let imageArray = [this.image]
```

Update api call function and inside the subsvribe convert this response to array object

```
getPokemonDetail(index) { return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/pokemon/${index}`) }
```

Comment: Thank you
I tried both of them, the errors are gone but I can't get the data.

getPokemonDetail(index) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/pokemon/${index}`).pipe(
      map((poke) => {
        let sprites = Object.keys(poke['sprites']);
        poke['images'] = sprites
          .map((spriteKey) => poke['sprites'][spriteKey])
          .filter((img) => img);
        return [poke];
      })
    );
  }

Comment: Can you share the response of the api?

Comment: in this link can you see it: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4